# Scope model update

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Below demo app is showing three different progressbars.

Now user needs to select which progressbar he/she wants to change value
and then on button click which is provided at same page.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.component('listComponent', {

  template:'<div ng-repeat="progress in $ctrl.obj.bars track by $index">' +
  '<progress value="{{progress}}" max="{{$ctrl.obj.limit}}">{{progress}}</progress><br>'+
  '</div>'+
  '<br>' +
  '<div>' +
  'Selected Progressbar : {{$ctrl.selectedProgressbar}}' +
  '<span>' +
  '<select name="selectedProgressbar" ng-model="$ctrl.selectedProgressbar">' +
  '<option ng-repeat="progress in $ctrl.obj.bars track by $index" value="{{$index}}">{{progress}}</option>' +
  '</select>' +
  '</span>' +
  '<span ng-repeat="btn in $ctrl.obj.buttons">' +
  '<button class="btn" ng-click="$ctrl.changeProgress(btn, $ctrl.selectedProgressbar)">{{btn}}</button>' +
  '</span>' +
  '</div>',
  controller: function () {

    this.obj = {
      "buttons": [
        10,
        38,
        -13,
        -18
      ],
      "bars": [
        62,
        45,
        62
      ],
      "limit": 230
    };

    function changeProgressbar(val){
      var val = parseInt(val);
      var barValue = this.obj.bars[this.selectedProgressbar];
      var selectedBar = this.selectedProgressbar;
      var bars = this.obj.bars;

      // this.obj.bars[0] = parseInt(this.obj.bars[0]) + parseInt(val);
      // if we remove comment from above code and comment below one then progresbar value changes at same time
      // but with below code its not changing at same time its changing when we click on any button or change progreebar selection
      if(val > 0){
        var total = parseInt(barValue) + val;

        var update = setInterval(function() {
          if (parseInt(barValue) > total) {
            clearInterval(update);    
          }
          barValue = parseInt(barValue) + 1;
          bars[selectedBar] = barValue;
        }, 15);
      }
    }
    this.changeProgress = changeProgressbar;
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="description" content="This is just demo application by using Angular 1.6">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Progressbar in Angular 1.6</title>
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
  progress:after {
      display: block;
      content: attr(value);
      text-align:center;
  }  
  </style>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <list-component></list-component>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
   
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[jsBin](https://jsbin.com/feyaguy/2/edit?html,output) is here,

now after selecting any progressbar then click on any first two buttons then no change is found on progreebar

but as soon as you click again or select some other progressbar then value is changing.

Comment: no better do this into directive, not as an application

Answer (score 0):

After going through your code, I found some issues there.

You should change the `changeProgressbar` function and remove the interval function.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="description" content="[add your bin description]">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Progressbar in Angular 1.6</title>
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
  progress:after {
      display: block;
      content: attr(value);
      text-align:center;
  }  
  </style>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <list-component></list-component>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
    app.component('listComponent', {
        // isolated scope binding
        template:'{{$ctrl.obj.bars}}<div ng-repeat="progress in $ctrl.obj.bars track by $index">' +
                  '<progress value="{{progress}}" max="{{$ctrl.obj.limit}}">{{progress}}</progress><br>'+
                 '</div>'+
                 '<br>' +
                 '<div>' +
                    'Selected Progressbar : {{$ctrl.selectedProgressbar}}' +
                    '<span>' +
                      '<select name="selectedProgressbar" ng-model="$ctrl.selectedProgressbar">' +
                          '<option ng-repeat="progress in $ctrl.obj.bars track by $index" value="{{$index}}">{{progress}}</option>' +
                      '</select>' +
                    '</span>' +
                    '<span ng-repeat="btn in $ctrl.obj.buttons">' +
                      '<button class="btn" ng-click="$ctrl.changeProgress(btn, $ctrl.selectedProgressbar)">{{btn}}</button>' +
                    '</span>' +
                  '</div>',
        controller: function () {
  
            this.obj = {
                "buttons": [
                    10,
                    38,
                    -13,
                    -18
                ],
                "bars": [
                    62,
                    45,
                    62
                ],
                "limit": 230
            };
  
            function changeProgressbar(val){
                var val = parseInt(val);
                var barValue = this.obj.bars[this.selectedProgressbar];
                var selectedBar = this.selectedProgressbar;
                var bars = this.obj.bars;
                
                // this.obj.bars[0] = parseInt(this.obj.bars[0]) + parseInt(val);
                // if we remove comment from above code and comment below one then progresbar value changes at same time
                // but with below code its not changing at same time its changing when we click on any button or change progreebar selection
                if(val > 0){
                    var total = parseInt(barValue) + val;
                     
                        if (parseInt(barValue) > total) {
                            clearInterval(update);    
                        }
                  else
                    {
                      barValue = total;
                      bars[selectedBar] = barValue;
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            this.changeProgress = changeProgressbar;
        }
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**PLEASE RUN THE ABOVE SNIPPET**

[Here is a working **DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/XtHlY4sJWiFPtIsOmcgh?p=preview)

Comment: @Nitish, please check my answer.